# Print to Wifi Printer from CN1 app

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to print from my CN1 app to a WiFi printer?

I don't want to print files. I want to print tables filled with data from my users.

I noticed this question from 3 years ago. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/RIizxJNZBHU. Hopefully there is something now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing new about this as it's a pretty niche requirement. When it was asked printing support was remarkably rare and now its just rare.

You can use a webservice like Google Cloud Print or use native interfaces to integrate with the printing API's e.g. see the developer guide sections about building cn1libs and working with native code: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html